# What are http headers and when do I need to specify them

Tags: php, laravel, download

I'm trying to download a file with laravel. I'm seeing a lot of examples that show the headers array with things link content-type/size etc.

My question is what are these headers and when do I need to set them

Sample of my code:

```
$file_path = public_path() . 'path/to/file' . $file_name;

        if (file_exists($file_path)) {
            return response()->download($file_path, $file_name);
        }
```

This works for me. But I've seen some examples add a headers array as a third argument and I'm curious to know the uses of it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to Google on the subject? Headers can be used for a lot of different things and there are many in depth tutorials etc about it. Just search for: "what are http headers" and then check out PHP's manual about the [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

Comment: type of data so the server would know what to exprect, lets say JSON, XML, etc... application/text ... You should use it in RESTful web services

You should google it, couse it's a big subject...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP Headers provide your webbrowser with extra information about the response it gets from a request. In your case, the `Content-type` header provides the browser with information about, believe it or not, the type of content the server returns. By specifying `Content-type: application/pdf` your browser will know it has to use the Adobe Reader plugin for example to display the content the server returns. You can find more information about HTTP headers [in this Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

You can use HTTP response headers in your Laravel application like this:

```
return new \Illuminate\Http\Response(file_path, 200, [
            'Content-type' =>  'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $file_name,
]);
```

Comment: you copy my answer code and forgot to fix the error I made in file_path hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
return new \Illuminate\Http\Response($file_path, 200, [
            'Content-type' =>  'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $file_name,
        ]);
```

this way we pass the right headers and to response will handle the return for the client